# Is there a way to keep on asking the user to input a number, so that each number inputted will contribute to the value of an existing dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the code I am working on:

```
ans = raw_input('Enter Amount of Players: ').lower()
cf={}
if ans == '2':
    p1 = raw_input('What is Player 1 named:')
    p2 = raw_input('What is Player 2 named:')
    cf[p1] = '50'
    cf[p2] = '50'
ques = raw_input('Enter Amount Name: ').lower()
if ques == p1:
    ques = p1
elif ques == p2:
    ques = p2
elif ques == p3:
    ques = p3
elif ques == p4:
    ques = p4
elif ques == p5:
    ques = p5
elif ques == p6:
    ques = p6
elif ques == p7:
    ques = p7
elif ques == p8:
    ques = p8

inc = raw_input(ques + ' Enter Amount of Increase: ').lower()
if inc > str(0):
    def cva(x):
        y = cf[ques]
        y = float(y)
        return x + y
    num = inc
    num = float(num)
    cf[ques]=cva(num)
    for item in cf:
        print item, cf[item]
```

How do I get this:

```
ques = raw_input('Enter Amount Name: ').lower()
if ques == p1:
    ques = p1
elif ques == p2:
    ques = p2
elif ques == p3:
    ques = p3
elif ques == p4:
    ques = p4
elif ques == p5:
    ques = p5
elif ques == p6:
    ques = p6
elif ques == p7:
    ques = p7
elif ques == p8:
    ques = p8

inc = raw_input(ques + ' Enter Amount of Increase: ').lower()
if inc > str(0):
    def cva(x):
        y = cf[ques]
        y = float(y)
        return x + y
    num = inc
    num = float(num)
    cf[ques]=cva(num)
    for item in cf:
        print item, cf[item]
```

To keep on repeating infinity? What I mean by this is when a user inputs a number, the number will be added to value that already exists in the dictionary. Is there a way to keep on asking the user to input a number, so that each number inputted will contribute to the value of the dictionary?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing all of those if statements? You are checking to see if it equals a certain value and if it does then you set it to the value it already equals?

Comment: Your code is difficult to read; you should clarify the expected result. Is the goal (1) input a string, (2) input a value, (3) increase the dictionary value associated with the string by the value?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need the nested `if...elif`. It's not useful to *set it by itself if it equals to itself*.
2. Use **`while True:`** to start a dead loop as you want to.
3. Define the function `def cva(x)` outside of the loop. You don't want to define it many times.
4. Replace `if inc > str(0)` with `if int(inc) > 0` to check if `inc` is greater than 0.

---

Try this:

```
ans = raw_input('Enter Amount of Players: ').lower()
cf={}
if ans == '2':
    p1 = raw_input('What is Player 1 named:')
    p2 = raw_input('What is Player 2 named:')
    cf[p1] = '50'
    cf[p2] = '50'

def cva(x):
    y = cf[ques]
    y = float(y)
    return x + y

while True:
    ques = raw_input('Enter Amount Name: ').lower()
    inc = raw_input(ques + ' Enter Amount of Increase: ').lower()
    if int(inc) > 0:
        cf[ques]=cva(float(inc))
        for item in cf:
            print item, cf[item]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to repeat something forever, you could try a while loop. For example:

```
p = True
while p == True:
```

You would put this at the start of the code that you want to repeat, and tab (or put 4 spaces) before each line that follows. Also, if you wanted to do it for a given number of times, you could do a for loop:

```
for x in range(1,1000):
#Change the 1000 to whatever number you want
```

You would put this in front of the code you wanted to repeat and tab the code over as well.
If this doesn't solve your problem, comment and say what you need me to fix.